# How to implement loader untill work in progress?

Tags: objective-c, json, ios7, xcode5, loader

I am new to ios Development. I need to call api to fetch information from web,in controller 2 i am calling my api to show information from web  and from controller 1's button action i am calling controller 2. I implemented  custom loader in controller 2 's view did load method in processing time but i don't know why it takes so much time to go controller 2 from controller 1 and i don't know how to reduce that processing time or can u please tell me can i implement loader in button action's processing time. need help.

to call api-

```
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:getAllClassifications                                                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                             timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest      returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    // NSLog(@"return id =%@",returnData);

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:returnData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
    //NSDictionary *location = [json objectForKey:@"npidata"];

    NSArray *latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"taxonomy"];
    recipes = [latestLoans valueForKey:@"classification"];


    firstname = [latestLoans valueForKey:@"classification"];
```

to implement custom loader-

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"loadingg" withExtension:@"gif"];
self.loader.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData     dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];


float progress = 0.0f;
while (progress < 1.0f) {

    progress += 0.01f;
    HUD.progress = progress;
    usleep(50000);





}

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:progress target:self selector:@selector(abcd) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Please include your code. You're probably doing network operations on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

@jrturton seems to have it right, you are doing `NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest` which will stop dead until all the data is returned. You will find the system more responsive using an asynchronous request.

```
NSURLConnection *c = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self startImmediately: true];
```

That then returns immediately to your code before the data is ready. later, it will call back to the delegate methods you also have to define, to give you the data as it comes in. There is a simple tutorial at http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/ and the extensive details at [the apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/initWithRequest%3adelegate%3astartImmediately%3a)